# Angular Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'select'

Tags: html, angular, typescript

**Error**
Building...X [ERROR] NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'select'. [plugin angular-compiler]

```
src/app/app.component.html:4:25:
  4 │     <select id="climate" [(ngModel)]="selectedClimate">
    ╵                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

```
src/app/app.component.ts:5:15:
  5 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="content">
  <div>
    <label for="climate">Clima:</label>
    <select id="climate" [(ngModel)]="selectedClimate">
      <option *ngFor="let climate of climateOptions" [value]="climate">{{ climate }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="weather">Tiempo:</label>
    <select id="weather" [(ngModel)]="selectedWeather">
      <option *ngFor="let weather of weatherOptions" [value]="weather">{{ weather }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <app-weather-image [selectedClimate]="selectedClimate" [selectedWeather]="selectedWeather"></app-weather-image>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WeatherImageComponent } from './weather-image/weather-image.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WeatherImageComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Please, help. Thank you

I tried modifying the mentioned files but ng serve still doesn't work

Comment: Include a name property whenever you use ngModel e.g. `<select id="climate" "name"="selectedClimate" [(ngModel)]="selectedClimate">` and if you're using RouterOutlet you need to import the RoutingModule to the module

Comment: Did you import ReactiveFormsModule ?